# listing all dates in column according to

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

   if ( $row['cbmonth'] == date("Y-m-d") ) {

      echo $row['last_name'];

   }else{

      echo "Nothing";

}

?>
```

Well this is working for me but it is only grabbing the first row.  What I am endeavoring to achieve is for all the rows with the matching dates to list using my conditional 'if' statement. In other words, I want the other three rows with dates which meet the if criteria to appear alongside the first column, which is the only appearing now.

Im imagining a while loop, fetch_num_rows but no success would appreciate any help here,
-Les

Comment: You need to include more information: is `$row` an array? How are you querying your data?

Comment: I queried the data in the opening page connection and the select query includes both relevant table as in select * from .....and the data required is all accessible.. yes variable row is an array

Comment: Show us the output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($row);`?

Comment: Im using procedural style...not PDO.

Comment: _"Im imagining a while loop, fetch_num_rows but no success"_ - Show us your attempt

Comment: Thank you all for assisting me I did not have my $row set up as an array aferall so if I could have I would have given the check to kisaragi, but sumit's answer also helped. Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try from SQL

```
$date= date("Y-m-d");

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT lastname FROM tbl WHERE cbmonth=? LIMIT 0,3")) {

    /* bind parameters  */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $date);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();
}
```